# Passing values in laravel through AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel

Iam trying to connect my database and admin panel by passing some data through it.

My controller looks like
// Getting State data for display in editing mdoal via AJAX

```
public function getblogdata(Request $request){
    $bloglists   = DB::table("bloglists")
    ->select(DB::raw("*"))
    ->where('bloglists.id' , '=', $request->uid)
    ->get();
    // $country = unserialize(base64_decode($bloglists[0]->country));
    // return response()->json( $country);
    // return response()->json( $bloglists, $country);
    return response()->json( $bloglists);
}
```

Note: I tried to pass multiple variables here but could not. Finally settled for one variable only.

My Ajax looks like

```
$('.edit_blog_btn').on('click', function () {
        var blog_sel = $(this).data('uid');
        // console.log($(this).data('uid'));
        if (blog_sel) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/get_blog_data?uid="+blog_sel, 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (res) {     
                    // console.log(res);
                    if(res){
                        $.each(res, function (key, value){
                            $("#blog-edit-title").val(value.title);
                            $("#blog-edit-c_img").empty();
                            $("#blog-edit-c_img").append('<span>Cover Image - </span><span></span><img src="/storage/cover_images/'+value.cover_img+'" alt=" " class="img-responsive" id="blog-edit-c_img"/><input name="cover_img" type="file">');
                            $("#blog-edit-url").val(value.url);
                            var country = res[0]['country'];
                            var state = res[0]['state'];
                            var sight = res[0]['sight'];
                            var tags = res[0]['tags'];
                            console.log("the country tag is " + country+ "the state tags is " +state+ "the sight tag is "+sight+ "tha tag tag is" +tags );

                        });                            
                    } else {
                        alert('Something weird just happened');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#blog-id").empty();
        }
    });
```

Note: I simply want pass the 4 variables along with other data to show in view

Comment: where do you want to pass the variables? You can use a get-request with a query or a post-request with a body for instance

Comment: I want to pass the variables (country, state, sight, tags) from AJAX to my view. Have no clue of how to do this.

Comment: @AmitKhare Instead of editing my answer to ask more questions, improve your OP and add your questions, so that we know what's the problem in the question, not the answer.

Comment: @senty Apologies for the error. this is the 3rd time I have asked a question on StackOverflow and had no intention or idea of OP. I was simply trying to convey the problem.

Comment: @AmitKhare Edit your question and add details in your question itself as you go down the road and identify your problem better (rather than editing below answers). Or if it's simple, just add comments to related answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return an `[key => value]` array for `return response->json()`.

```
public function getblogdata(Request $request){
    $bloglists   = DB::table("bloglists")
    ->select(DB::raw("*"))
    ->where('bloglists.id' , '=', $request->uid)
    ->get();

    $country = unserialize(base64_decode($bloglists[0]->country));

    return response()->json([
        'bloglists' => $bloglists,
        'country' => $country
    ]);
}
```

Now, in your ajax after response, try

```
console.log(res.data);
console.log(response.data.bloglists)
console.log(response.data.country)
```

Comment: Guys, Iam still not able to pass the value through AJAX. XCan anyone help please. For example var country = res[0]['country']; . How to pass this value?